# Как получить список организаций в радиусе 1 км в Яндекс Карты?

Tags: яндекс-карта-api

Есть координаты станции метро. Например:
Перово 55,75098 37,78422

Как можно получить список организаций, которые находятся в радиусе 1 км от станции метро.

[https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Ломбард&results=50&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=](https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4&results=50&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=)

Благодарю!